# Axis2 1.6.2 eclipse plugins not showing

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis

I'm running Eclipse Juno (4.2.1.x), I've downloaded axis2 plugins version 1.6.2:

```
org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.6.2.jar
org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.6.2.jar
```

I put them into my dropins folder, started Eclipse and they are not being installed. They are not in the menu and when I look at installed plugins via help/about they are not listed.

I even tried putting them into the plugins folder.

I read there was a problem with 1.6.1 but this is 1.6.2.

btw, after starting/stopping eclipse they are still in the dropins folder. I'm assuming if installed they should go? I also ran with -console mode and saw no errors.

Any help would be appreciated.